# print array content in one line

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class morse {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word = "word";
    String[] alphabet = {"a.-", "b-...", "c-.-.", "d-..", "e.", "f..-.", "g--.", "h....", "i..", "j.---", "k-.-", "l.-..", "m--","n-.", "o---", "p.--.", "q--.-", "r.-.", "s...", "t-", "u..-", "v...-", "w.--", "x-..-", "y-.--", "z--.."};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length() ; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++) {
        if (alphabet[j].charAt(0) == word.charAt(i)) {
          System.out.println(alphabet[j].substring(1).toString());
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

how can i print that in one line

i tried applying .toString at the end of the if condition but that also didnt work and it was still the same, i was  mostly trying to find a simple solution.

Comment: Please [edit] the post and format the code properly.

Comment: Stop using `println` if you don't want a new line. Tangential: it'd probably be better to gather the results in a list and `join` them, and use a hash to look up the translations, e.g., `String -> String`.

Comment: @DaveNewton note that hash and map aren't the same thing even though they are sometimes used incorrectly as synonyms. Hashes can be used for data structures that aren't maps and maps can be implemented without hashes.

Comment: @sprinter Noted. One danger of being a full-time polyglot is translating between languages. I'm fully aware of the technical definitions of the words, but different languages use different terms (e.g., Ruby hashes).

Comment: @DaveNewton yep understood and agree. I honestly think that was poor naming in Ruby - confusing implementation and interface. Data structures are pretty hard for beginners to get their heads around so I'm a bit (too?) obsessed about accurate naming!

Answer (score 0):

So, you could modify the code and create a method to convert a single char to a morse code string.
Then, you just need to do three simple steps to this string.

1. Split the string into a list of chars
2. Using the Streams Library (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) map that list of chars to a list of strings
3. Simply join the list of strings into a single string separated by a space

```java
public class Main {
  static String[] alphabet = {"a.-", "b-...", "c-.-.", "d-..", "e.", "f..-.", "g--.", "h....", "i..", "j.---", "k-.-", "l.-..", "m--","n-.", "o---", "p.--.", "q--.-", "r.-.", "s...", "t-", "u..-", "v...-", "w.--", "x-..-", "y-.--", "z--.."};
    
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word = "word";
    String morseCode = word.chars()
        .mapToObj(c -> charToMorse((char) c))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    System.out.println(morseCode);
  }

  public static String charToMorse(char c) {
    for (int j = 0; j < alphabet.length; j++) {
      if (alphabet[j].charAt(0) == Character.toLowerCase(c)) {
        return alphabet[j].substring(1);
      }
    }
    return "";
  }
}
```